# Bash - extra quotes are needed when checking file existence with if [ -f ]; tried with [] and [[ ]], both needs ''

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a function checking file existence with `if [ -f ]` in bash. When path name has space, it usually does not need extra single quotes around the path variable for bash to detect its existence. But here I need it.

The correct, working version of my bash function:

```bash
backup-to-onedrive() {
    if [[ -z "$*" ]]; then
        echo "Copy files to OneDrive dirs with subdir structure preserved, and as hard link, so they always stay in sync. "
        echo "Example: cp-backup-hardlink \"C:\application\" \"sublime-text-4/Data/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap\" \"config\""
        return 1
    fi 
    check-arg "$1" "Provide the copy starting point dir, for example C:\application\\" || exit 1
    check-arg "$2" "Provide the file to copy, relative path starting from $1, for example sublime-text-3/Data/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap" || exit 1
    check-arg "$3" "Provide the dir under C:\Users\WesternGun\OneDrive\backup-everything\, in Linux path format(with slash), for example 'config'" || exit 1

    target="C:\Users\WesternGun\OneDrive\backup-everything"
    rootdir="$(win-path-to-linux $1)"
    if ! [ -d "$rootdir" ]; then
        echo "$rootdir does not exist"
        return 1
    fi
    cd "$rootdir"
    echo "Backup from $rootdir"

    tobackup="$(win-path-to-linux "$2")"
    echo "$2 converted to linux path: $tobackup"
    if [ -f '"$tobackup"' ]; then                         # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< this line needs single quotes around the expanded var to work if `$tobackup` contains space
        echo "$tobackup does not exist"
        return 1
    fi
    echo "File to back up: "$tobackup""

    targetdir="$(win-path-to-linux "$target/$3")"
    if ! [ -d "$targetdir" ]; then
        echo "$targetdir does not exist, mkdir"
        mkdir -p "$targetdir"
    fi
    echo "Back up to $targetdir"

    # -a = --archive = "same as -dR --preserve=all" = "never follow symbolic links in SOURCE", --preserve=links, and "copy directories recursively", 
    # while -l means "hard link files instead of copying"
    # --parents: copy all file tree structure
    # cp -al --parents "sublime-text-4/Data/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap" "$(win-path-to-linux "C:\Users\WesternGun\OneDrive\backup-everything\config\sublime-text-4")"
    cp -al --parents "$tobackup" "$targetdir"
    cd -
}
```

All relevant functions used above:

```bash
win-path-to-linux() {
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Please provide Windows path, will convert to Linux path. For example, 'C:\Windows\System32' will become '/mnt/c/Windows/System32'. "
        echo "Single-quote the path!"
        return 1
    fi

    # first switch case for partition letter, replace ':\' to '/', then, replace '\' to '/'. OR pattern not working with '|'. Syntax is "sed 's/(pattern)/(replace)/'".
    # \L\x: convert captured group to lower case. \U\x: upper case , g: replace all
    # only '' will preserve '\', "" will interprete and remove it. But I cannot do "" and '' at the same time, so the arg needs to be quoted

    # we only have C drive in my computer and matching a letter has some difficulty, so here simplify it:
    result=
    if [[ "$1" =~ ^C:\\ ]]; then
        result="/mnt/$1"
    else
        result="$1"
    fi
    echo "$result" | sed -E 's/(\w):\\/\L\1\//g' | sed -E 's/\\/\//g'
}


check-arg() {
    # provide the arg to check, and the error message
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "$2"
        return 1
    fi
}
```

I also create a test function to show the normal working syntax without extra quotes:

```bash
test_file() {
    cd "$1"
    if [ -f "$2" ]; then
        echo Exists
    else
        echo Does not exist
    fi;
}
```

The output when it has NO extra single quotes:(error)

```bash
$ backup-to-onedrive "C:\Users\WesternGun" "AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml" "config"
Backup from /mnt/c/Users/WesternGun
AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml converted to linux path: AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml
AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml does not exist
```

Expected output(when single quotes present):

```bash
$ backup-to-onedrive "C:\Users\WesternGun" "AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml" "config"
Backup from /mnt/c/Users/WesternGun
AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml converted to linux path: AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml
File to back up: AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml
Back up to /mnt/c/Users/WesternGun/OneDrive/backup-everything/config
/mnt/c/Users/WesternGun
```

And file is indeed copied.

Running the test function `test-file`:

```bash
$ test_file "/mnt/c/Users/WesternGun" "AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml"
Exists
```

So in this case:

```
if [ -f "$tobackup" ];
```

does not work, but I need to put

```
if [ -f '"$tobackup"' ];
```

why?

Bash version:

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

EDIT:

Adding a minimal example; other functions also used so cannot get rid of. and `set -x` too.

```bash
backup-to-onedrive-test ()
{
    set -x;
    tobackup="$(win-path-to-linux "$2")";
    echo "$2 converted to linux path: $tobackup";
    if [[ -f "$tobackup" ]]; then
        echo "$tobackup does not exist";
        return 1;
    fi;
    echo "File to back up: "$tobackup""
}
```

output:

```bash
$ backup-to-onedrive-test "C:\Users\WesternGun" "AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml" "config"
backup-to-onedrive-test "C:\Users\WesternGun" "AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml" "config"
++ win-path-to-linux 'AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml'
++ '[' -z 'AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml' ']'
++ result=
++ [[ AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml =~ ^C:\\ ]]
++ result='AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml'
++ echo 'AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml'
++ sed -E 's/(\w):\\/\L\1\//g'
++ sed -E 's/\\/\//g'
+ tobackup='AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml'
+ echo 'AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml converted to linux path: AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml'
AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml converted to linux path: AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml
+ [[ -f AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml ]]
+ echo 'AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml does not exist'
AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.3/keymaps/Windows copy.xml does not exist
+ return 1
```

Comment: Make a _minimal_ [MCVE]. Remove code until you are left with the bare minimum to reproduce. Let's remove all the backuping, argument checking, error checking. Please then add `set -x` on top of the script and post the output in both cases. `Bash version` Cygwin?

Comment: I am working with WSL 2 + Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: OK simplified function added, `set -x` set, plus output.

Comment: so what is the set -x output with `[ -f '"$tobackup"' ]` ? I think `cd` is needed, no?

Comment: Yes, maybe false since you're not currently in your home directory?

Comment: If test `-f '"$tobackup"'` passes then you likely have a file named `"$tobackup"`

Comment: Please reduce your question to a [mcve], posting multiple blocks of code, the contents of most of which have nothing to do with the problem you're asking for help with, and nothing we could simply execute ourselves to try to reproduce the problem, just makes it that much harder for anyone to be able to help you. Chances are by going through the process of creating a [mcve] you won't even need help, you'll figure it out for yourself.

Comment: And please also do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.", don't ask people to have to wade through a bunch of issues that a tool could have caught for you trying to guess which might be your problem when maybe none of them are.

Comment: For testing whether the string stored in the variable `tobackup` is the path to a plain file, a `[[ -f $tobackup ]]` would do. `[ -f '"$tobackup"' ]` tests the existence of a file with the literal name `"$tobackup"`. BTW, I find your "reproducible example" not really useful. A reproducible example would consist of a file creation, followed by a file test: `var="bla bla"; : >"$var"; [[ -f $var ]]; echo $?` would be such a simple example.

Comment: I'm positive that with very little effort you could create a complete script about 10 lines long or less that would reproduce your problem, assuming doing that doesn't show you the solution to your problem, and that we could then copy/paste to test with so we could help you. That plus a couple of example file names and the expected output is the [mcve] we're looking for and then you can delete all of that other code from your question.

Comment: `if [ -f '"$tobackup"' ]; then echo "$tobackup does not exist"; return 1`, are you sure? You're basically coding the equivalent of "_if file exists, say that it does not exist and return error_" ...

Answer (score -1):

Understanding how quotes work is a big part of shell programming. In shell scripts quotes do NOT work like they do in most other languages but only control which meta-characters are processed within the quotes.

A simple description is:

- '  single quote: Treat all characters as regular characters until the next single quote.
- "  double quote: start a "word", including spaces, until the next double quote. The use of single quotes ate the entire double quoted expression, which is not a file name.

Non-quoted white spaces, along with a few meta-characters, make word breaks.  Quoted white space to not make word breaks.

if [ -f "$tobackup" ]; then              # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Educational examples:

echo 'var=$'"$var";
print var=$ followed by value of $var.
The fact there is no space between '" makes a single word.